# Delphi Masks.MatchesMask() disable sets [] brackets

Tags: delphi

Is there a way to disable sets [] when using Masks.MatchesMask() function?

So I can match also brackets characters like this:

```
if MatchesMask('C:\Path\File[Name.dat', 'C:\*\File[*.dat') then ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert bracket char to a set of a bracket char:

```
MatchesMask('C:\Path\File[Name.dat', 'C:\*\File[[]*.dat')
```